# Client 'Raven-Java 0.4' raised API error

Tags: java, sentry, raven

I'm trying to setup a local sentry on my server.

When my java app send an exception to the server, sentry returns "Client 'Raven-Java 0.4' raised API error:" (no error displayed).

JSON data for this exception in sentry:
`{"id": "4f8e8377122340da92c7192c9a059aea", "checksum": "5c99c531830313a994bf4de2e8bb4fd4", "project": "default", "logger": "sentry.api.http", "level": "error", "culprit": "", "extra": {"thread": -1219086144, "process": 8395, "threadName": "MainThread", "module": "api", "filename": "api.py", "pathname": "/opt/sentry/lib/python2.5/site-packages/sentry-4.4.6-py2.5.egg/sentry/web/api.py", "lineno": 153, "message": "Client 'Raven-Java 0.4' raised API error: ", "funcName": "store"}, "modules": {"sentry": "4.4.6", "djcelery": "2.5.5", "django": "1.3.1", "kombu.transport.django": "1.0.0", "kombu": "2.1.8", "south": "0.7.5", "raven": "1.9.1"}, "sentry.interfaces.Message": {"message": "Client 'Raven-Java 0.4' raised API error: ", "params": []}}`

I'm able to send the same exception from my java app to the getsentry public server.

What's wrong?

Comment: nop still not found how to fix this problem... do you have the same problem?

Comment: i had the same with raven python client. Client version was 1.9.4, while server 1.8.some. BTW **sentry server logs its own exceptions**, it should give some hint of what went wrong.

Comment: The log is not very usefull, I pasted the JSON data from this exception on the question.  I expect an error message after "Client 'Raven-Java 0.4' raised API error: ", but the error is missing.

Comment: indeed, it tells that you have "sentry": "4.4.6" (4.4.6 is version number). Probably you have to check what is supported by that version.